# Getting foreign key columns metadata from view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Question is in the title :). I need to know if it is possible or not.

Here is how to do it for table

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) as tbl, 
    OBJECT_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id) as refTable, 
    COL_NAME(f.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) as foreignKeyColumnName 
FROM sys.foreign_keys f 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
WHERE f.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are typically just "pre-stored" `SELECT` statements based on tables.

Views themselves don't have any physical representation in your database, and therefore, you don't have foreign keys on views - you have them on the underlying base tables

Comment: Thanks Marc, maybe it is possible to get it from assoc tables through view.

Comment: @Danil: sure - you just need to know what tables the view relies on and then use your code you've posted..